# XM Cloud GraphQL CORs preflight endpoint configuration Issue

Tags: jss, graphql, xm-cloud

`XM Cloud GraphQL` CORs preflight endpoint configuration Issue
I am trying to execute the `GraphQL query` from my application in localhost, but I am unable to get the results, although the query works on graphql Playground and Postman

when I debugged I found the issue console error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge/ide/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: The endpoint URL should be https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge by changing the end point URL this issue got fixed.